# How to read json with this format

Tags: java, android, json

how can i read this JSON format,and user can pass the from and to  into URL, 
and want to  print these from_amount and to_amount into the text view on button click.

[api url](http://devel.farebookings.com/api/curconversor/%5Bfrom%5D/%5B%20to%5D/%5Bamount%5D/json%20;)

```
{
  "from": "INR",
  "to": "GBP",
  "from_amount": 2,
  "to_amount": 0.019798718798321
}
```

i tried to do the snippet below.,but it is not returning any thing and also not giving any error in thr log cat

```
 private static final String API_URL = "http://devel.farebookings.com/api/curconversor/t1/t2/usds/json";
    if (!usdValue.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                        AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();

                        client.get(API_URL, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {


                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(String response) {
                                Log.i("CHACHING", "HTTP Sucess");

                                try {
                                    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(response);
                                    JSONObject ratesObject = jsonObj
                                            .getJSONObject("from");
                                    JSONObject ratessObject = jsonObj
                                            .getJSONObject("to");

                                    JSONObject rates2Object = jsonObj
                                            .getJSONObject("from_amount");
                                    //Double RateTo = Double.valueOf(t2
                                        //  .toString());

                                    Double RateFrom = Double.valueOf(t1
                                            .toString());
                                //  Double RateFrom = ratesObject.getDouble("from");
                                    //Double RateTo = ratesObject.getDouble(t2.toString());
                                    //Log.i("CHACHING", "GBP: " + gbpRate);
                                    //Log.i("CHACHING", "EUR: " + eurRate);

                                    Double usds = Double.valueOf(usdValue.getText()
                                            .toString());

                                    //Double gbps = usds * RateFrom;
                                //  Double euros = usds * RateTo;
                                    //Result.setText("ConvertedFrom: "
                                        //  + String.valueOf(RateFrom)+ "ConvertedTo: "
                                                //  + String.valueOf(RateTo));
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                            Result.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                            .show();

                                    //ConvertedTo.setText("ConvertedTo: "
                                            //+ String.valueOf(RateTo));

                                }
```

Comment: What did you try? What are you having trouble with? What language?

Comment: @  SLaks i update my question

Comment: what is you issue? the output log?

Comment: @  BlaShadow i dont know hoe to pass user's choice in the url,so as to read that specific data from the api.above coade giving me whole of the json data.but i want user choose value from dropdown and that particular value come as  a result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use the `getJsonObject()` method to get the values inside the JSONObject, but use the corresponding getters for the types of the values. The key-value pairs themselves are no JSONObjects.

```
 JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(response);

 String fromCurrency = jsonObj.getString("from");
 String toCurrency= jsonObj.getJSONObject("to");
 Double fromAmount = jsonObj.getDouble("from_amount");
 Double toAmount= jsonObj.getDouble("to_amount");
```